# In kabbalah what are the אוצרות?

Tags: mysticism-kabbalah

I was listening to a shiur from a Rav and I heard him refer to "the אוצרות" as one of the fundamental introductions to limud hakabbalah. 
Which sefer is he referring to?

Comment: See this question: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/18831/where-did-the-book-otzrot-hayyim-come-from

Comment: https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A6%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%AA_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D It is one of the books written by Rabbi Chayim Vittal.